# How do I really uninstall Chrome Frame?

Tags: google-chrome, uninstall

Just as described [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/MfRfcabCabM/w8-6GGbwvzkJ) and other places, I can't uninstall the Google Chrome Frame add-on for IE.  I don't want to just break it by getting rid of appropriate Registry entries, but rather want to uninstall "properly".  Using `\setup.exe --uninstall --multi-install --chrome-frame`, a pop-up window that says the uninstall was successful, but it doesn't actually remove the Reg keys or `c:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\`  subfolders.

Do I need to run the .msi (I can find the Enterprise one) with an uninstall switch?

It is OK if Chrome is uninstalled temporarily as well, but I need to completely uninstall Chrome Frame.  This is on a WinXP machine with IE7, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you reboot after uninstalling it? Things may not get deleted until the next reboot.  Have you tried reinstalling it and then uninstalling it again, ensuring no instances of it or IE are running when you do it?

Comment: I did try uninstall via cmd line (no IE instances running), and yes I did reboot.   I haven't tried reinstall and uninstall, but will give that a go.

Comment: Before I reinstall and uninstall I think I need to find out a bit more.  I am reading where people are running into issues having both versions on their machine.  I wonder if it makes a difference if the first install was done with the consumer or enterprise install?

Comment: In chrome_frame_installer.log I see (Install distribution: Google Chrome binaries...VERBOSE1:install_util.cc(227)] Windows NT 5.1 SP3
...VERBOSE1:setup_main.cc(880)]) but it's not clear if it's the Enterprise or Consumer version. This line (Command Line: "C:\DOCUME~1\<user>\LOCALS~1\Temp\CR_41381.tmp\setup.exe" --install-archive="C:\DOCUME~1\<user>\LOCALS~1\Temp\CR_41381.tmp\CHROME.PACKED.7Z" --chrome-frame --do-not-create-shortcuts --do-not-register-for-update-launch --verbose-logging --do-not-launch-chrome --multi-install --critical-update-version=22.0.1229.94) also isn't definitive.

Comment: The version listed in this installer log appears to be from the original install.  In <user>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application I only see folders for versions 26.0.1410.64 and 27.0.1453.94 ... so what I'm getting at is... does it matter if I reinstall with the Enterprise .msi or should I try to reinstall with the same version (consumer or enterprise) that already exists on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was using the command line uninstall was because it wasn't showing up in Add/Remove programs as that user.  On my machine, with admin rights, I can uninstall just fine that way.  The issue was solved by temporarily granting admin rights to this user to do the uninstall.  One wouldn't think admin rights would be needed to uninstall something that doesn't need the rights to do the install in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I know you resolved this on your own but if you need to remove Google Chrome Frame plug in and many systems you can do this silently and with a command line. You will need the [MSI installer from Google](http://www.google.com/chromeframe/eula.html?msi=true).

Then just run

`msiexec /x {1F0342F5-8369-3CD1-99DD-E9BC44473708} /q`